# Understanding memory alignment constraints and padding bytes in C

Tags: c, struct, padding, sizeof

I  have following code snippet.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    typedef struct{
        int a;
        int b;
        int c;
        char ch1;
        int d;
    } str;
    printf("Size: %d \n",sizeof(str));
    return 0;
}
```

Which is giving output as follows

```
Size: 20
```

I know that size of the `structure` is greater than the summation of the sizes of components of the `structure` because of padding added to satisfy memeory alignment constraints.
I want to know how it is decided that how many bytes of padding have to be added. On what does it depend ? Does it depends on CPU architecture ? And does it depends on compiler also ? I am using here 64bit CPU and `gcc` compiler. How will the output change if these parameters change.

I know there are similar questions on StackOverflow, but they do not explain this memory alignment constraints thoroughly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It in general depends on the requirements of the architecture. There's loads over [here](http://www.catb.org/esr/structure-packing/), but it can be summarized as follows:

> Storage for the basic C datatypes on an x86 or ARM processor doesn’t
>   normally start at arbitrary byte addresses in memory. Rather, each
>   type except char has an alignment requirement; chars can start on any
>   byte address, but 2-byte shorts must start on an even address, 4-byte
>   ints or floats must start on an address divisible by 4, and 8-byte
>   longs or doubles must start on an address divisible by 8. Signed or
>   unsigned makes no difference.

In your case the following is probably taking place: `sizeof(str) = 4 (4 bytes for int) + 4 (4 bytes for int) + 1 ( 1 byte for char) + 7 (3 bytes padding + 4 bytes for int) = 20`

The padding is there so that `int` is at an address that's a multiple of 4 bytes. This requirement comes from the fact that `int` is 4 bytes long (my assumption regarding the architecture you're using). But this will vary from one architecture to another.

Answer (score 1):

> On what does it depend ? Does it depends on CPU architecture ? And does it depends on compiler also ?

CPU, operating system, and compiler at least.

Answer (score 0):

I know that it depends on the CPU architecture, I think you can find some interesting articles that talks about this on the net, [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment) is not bad in my opinion.

For me I am using a 64 bit linux machine, and what I can say is that, every field is aligned so that it would be on a memory address divisible by its size (for basic types), for example :

`int` and `float` are aligned by 4 (must be in a memory adress divisible by 4)

`char` and `bool` by 1 ( which means no padding)

`double` and `pointers` are aligned by 8

Best way to avoid padding is to put your fields from largest size to smallest (when there is only basic fields)

When there is composed fields, it a little more difficult for me to explain here, but I think you can figure it out yourself in a paper